# How to disable comments in node.tpl?

Tags: 6, theming, comments

I decided to programatically print comments un Views using PHP footer. The problem is that they now appears twice (my code + default). When I disable comments in content type settings, both ddisappear. How can I disable the default comments and keep my comments printed by php code? I tried to edit node.tpl file. but there is no section responsible for showing comments there (I use Garland). Any advice appreciated.

Comment: could you be a little more specific? How would you like to display comments in your own PHP code? What's the difference? What about using Panels rather than Views+footer? (It would be good to better understand your problem not to advise things that don't match your case...)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried looking into the comment.tpl.php file?

You should be able to hide the 'real' db driven comments there and only display your printed comments.

Comment: I've checked it, but I don't want to alter their appearance, I just would like to remove the duplicate. What should I edit there? Also I could diable them in the database, but I am afraid that it would also disable my programatically created comments.